# jQuery .live() to .on() with reference to "this"

Tags: jquery

I have read through the API documentation for converting .live() to .on() and it seems simple enough. However, in my code, I refernce "this" which references the actual object (checkbox) when using .live(), but now it will reference the document instead. I've attempted to change "this" to the actual object that "this" used to refer to when using .live(), but that did not work out. Here is an example of how I was using it. This is a gridview with a field for checkboxes and a checkbox in the header cell of the that field. When the checkbox in the header cell is checked, it checks all boxes in the body cells of that field and subsequently, when when it is unselected, the checkboxes in the body cells become unselected. Any advice would be helpful.

```
           $("[id*=CheckAll]").live("click", function () {
            var chkHeader = $(this);
            var grid = $(this).closest("table");
            $("input[type=checkbox]:visible", grid).each(function () {
                if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                    $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
                } else {
                    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                    $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
                }
            });
```

Updated code to use .on()

```
        $(document).on("click", "[id*=CheckAll]", function () {
            var chkHeader = $("[id*=CheckAll]");
            var grid = $("[id*=CheckAll]").closest("table");
            $("input[type=checkbox]:visible", grid).each(function () {
                if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                    $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
                } else {
                    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                    $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
                }
            });
```

I'm thinking how I need to get a reference to CheckAll is different than before when just using "this". It's possible that "this" was smart enough to reference only the current row's checkbox and when I reference like above it does not know which instance of that control to reference?

Comment: This is the old code, right? Can you also post the new code that doesn't work?

Comment: could you make a fiddle with the html, $(this).attr is deprecated as well, change to $(this).prop('checked',true);

Comment: Deprecated should be okay, right? live() has simply been removed altogether and throws error when compiling. I could give it a try though if you think it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying all sorts of things, it seems that replacing the .attr() functions with .prop() in all instances has gotten it working as expected. I imagine those being in there was causing the code to stop prematurely and not execute the remainder of the statements.

Proposed by: user1572796 in a comment below my original post.

Thanks everyone,
Jason

Answer (score 2):

> However, in my code, I refernce "this" which references the actual object (checkbox) when using .live(), but now it will reference the document instead.

No, it won't. Within the callback to `$("[id*=CheckAll]").live("click", ...)` and `$(document).on("click", "[id*=CheckAll]", ...)`, `this` refers to the same thing: The matching `CheckAll` element. Within a delegated `on` handler, `this` is the element that's the target of delegation, not the container element on which the event is hooked, just as it was with `live`.

E.g.:

```
$("#some-container").on("click", ".some-descendant", function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to a `.some-descendant` element, not `#some-container`
});
```

From your comment below:

> If I'm understanding, then that's what I had originally thought. So, I guess I'm looking for how to reference the target in subsequent statements of that function rather than using "this".

Then it's really unclear what you're asking. Referring to the above:

- `this` and [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) are `.some-descendant`
- [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is where the event originated (`.some-descendant`, or a descendant of it)
- [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) is `#some-container`

Full Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/rorica/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click "foo" below:</p>
  <div id="some-container">
    <div>
      <div class="some-descendant">
        <div>
          <div id="foo">foo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";

      $("#some-container").on("click", ".some-descendant", function(event) {
        display("this: " + describe(this));
        display("event.target: " + describe(event.target));
        display("event.currentTarget: " + describe(event.currentTarget));
        display("event.delegateTarget: " + describe(event.delegateTarget));
      });

      function describe(element) {
        var name = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (element.id) {
          name += "#" + element.id;
        }
        if (element.className) {
          name += "." + element.className.replace(/ /g, ".");
        }
        return name;
      }

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('pre');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And that's for your convenience, really, as it allows delegated handlers to run in the context of the actual target, not the delegated one. If you want your handler to run in the context of the delegated element, bind directly to it and test the `target` property of the event argument against your selector.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Not really, there are lots of use cases where you just don't want to bind directly. Regardless of delegation or not, `event.target` refers to the element where the event originated: http://jsbin.com/fubuha/2

Comment: I think we're in agreement here. I was only trying to add to your *`this` is the element that's the target of delegation, not the container element on which the event is hooked* statement by saying that's a *good* thing, but if for some reason you want to work around this feature, then you can :)

Comment: So, "this" does reference the target and not the container?

Comment: @Jason: `this` references the element that matched the delegated selector, just as it did with `live`. (That's not necessarily `event.target`, it could be an ancestor of it; it's what's specified by the delegation selector.)

Comment: If I'm understanding, then that's what I had originally thought. So, I guess I'm looking for how to reference the target in subsequent statements of that function rather than using "this". I've tried many ways so far and am not getting the expected results, although that may not be the source of why it is not working. I struggle a bit with debugging jQuery in VS because I don't know of a way to step through it.

Comment: @Jason: It's really unclear what you're looking for, so I've taken a scatter-shot approach; see the updated answer. I can't tell whether you're looking for `event.target`, `event.currentTarget`, or `event.delegateTarget`, but hopefully you're looking for one of them. :-)